Как убрать окно ошибке в скопилированном py файле использующем telebot
Сделал небольшого бота на python с использованием telebot. Но вот проблема: при компиляции в exe и запуске, если на устройстве нет интернета вылезет окно с ошибкой, что нет интернета. А можно как то убрать это окно, и заставить бота ждать пока интернет не появится?

try-except?
